# Странная операция С#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#

Недавно наткнулся на интересную [статью](http://jacob4u2.posterous.com/mvc-3-long-polling-comet-chat-example), описывающуюу реализацию Comet приложения на ASP.NET MVC(в конце статьи есть ссылка на [demo](http://mvcchatsite.apphb.com/) - открываем в 2-х браузерах/вкладках и переписываемся). Там есть интересный метод:

```
public static void CheckForMessagesAsync(Action<List<MessageInfo>> onMessages)
    {
        var queued = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(parm =>
        {
            var msgs = new List<MessageInfo>();
            var wait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            using (var subscriber = _messages.Subscribe(msg =>
                                            {
                                                msgs.Add(msg);
                                                wait.Set();
                                            }))
            {
                // Wait for the max seconds for a new msg
                wait.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaxWaitSeconds));                    
            }

            ((Action<List<MessageInfo>>)parm)(msgs);//что за операция? О_о
        }), onMessages);

        if (!queued)
            onMessages(new List<MessageInfo>());
    }
```

использование:

```
public void IndexAsync()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

        ChatServer.CheckForMessagesAsync(msgs =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["response"] = new ChatResponse
            {
                messages = msgs
            };
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        });
    }
```

Хотя метод непонятен чуть менее, чем полностью, но что делает строка, отмеченая комментом? как это операция называется?
Не пожалею о разъяснении всего метода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((Action<List<MessageInfo>>)parm)(msgs);
```

В этой строчке переменная `parm` приводится к типу [Action< T >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx). Он является делегатом, который можно вызвать. И он вызывается с параметром `msgs`.

Касательно остального кода (оператора =>), возможно ясность внесут [лямбда выражения](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: т.е. таким образом производится привидение(casting) делегатов?
нет, с лямбда всё ясно=)

Comment: Таким образом производится кастинг всего. В частности, делегатов.